# How to add offset support to EndpointsModel.query_method?

Tags: endpoints-proto-datastore

Due to the need to support an interface that works with offset, count, I can't rely on nextPageToken alone.  Therefor I'm trying to add offset support to `EndpointsModel.query_method()`.  I've taken the strategy of mimic'ing the limit code already present (both in `EndpointsModel` and `_EndpointsQueryInfo`), but for some reason offset won't show up in the api descriptor.

Any advise?  Happy to supply the patch if that makes an answer easier.

Update: there was something stale in my environment apparently.  I'll file a feature request to add support for additional supported QueryOptions keywords.

Comment: Have you resolved this? I didn't see a bug yet on the tracker.

Comment: Should we close this?

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  There's an outstanding [pull request](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/pull/76)